# PyQt5 How to detect which button is pressed when i'm drag and drop-ing

Tags: python, events, pyqt5, drag-and-drop

So I have button, I click it and spawn button(barTable class). Result is first button with text Table 1, next Table 2 etc... Right click on a button, holding, moving and releasing mouse click will move spawned button.

The problem is when I try to drag and drop Table 1 it works as intended, but if I spawn another button, Table 2, dragging and dropping Table 1 will move Table 2 and Table 1 will no longer have that function.

Now that happens because mainMenu saves only one button (def addTable). I don't know much about drag and drop, so I don't know if maybe I need to put all code for drag and drop inside barTable class or maybe to keep track of which button is clicked, which I also don't know how to do.

Any help is appreciated.

```
class mainMenu(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.rearrangeToggle = False
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def initUI(self):...

    def addTable(self):
        self.btn = barTable(self)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        self.btn.move(position)
        e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()
```

```
class barTable(QPushButton):

    allTables = []  # write

    def __init__(self, win):
        super().__init__(win)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 60, 50)
        self.allTables.append(self)
        self.setText("Table\n" + str(len(self.allTables)))  # write
        self.show()

    # Drag and drop
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != Qt.RightButton:
            return

        mimeData = QMimeData()

        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        dropAction = drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
```

Edit: Here is example that you can run (right click to drag and drop)

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication


class mainMenu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 550, 450)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.spawnButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.spawnButton.move(150, 150)
        self.spawnButton.show()
        self.spawnButton.setText('Spawn')
        self.spawnButton.clicked.connect(self.addTable)

    def addTable(self):
        self.btn = barTable(self)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        self.btn.move(position)
        e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()


class barTable(QPushButton):

    allTables = []  # write

    def __init__(self, win):
        super().__init__(win)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 60, 50)
        self.allTables.append(self)
        self.setText("Table\n" + str(len(self.allTables)))  # write
        self.show()

    # Drag and drop
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != Qt.RightButton:
            return

        mimeData = QMimeData()

        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        dropAction = drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainMenu()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: create an [mre]

Comment: Use the event's [`source`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdropevent.html#source): `e.source().move(position)`. Note that you should ***always*** either check for the mimedata's [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#data) (which you must set with a suitable mime type and value that *you* can recognize, before calling `drag.exec()`), or, for simple cases (that don't involve other drag and drop operations in the program) at least check *if* the source is valid and belongs to the application (eg. `e.source() is not None`).